# differnce in ADCs of Atmega and STM

Tags: embedded, stm32, avr, atmega, adc

In STM32F103 there are 2 ADCs and in ATMEGA328 there are 5 ADCs, now, if I am using 3 of the 5 ADC channel in AVR to measure three different analog inputs, is it same as using 3 regular groups of either of ADC1 or ADC2 of the STM?
or can we just using only two ADCs in STM? I am confused

Comment: I think this question is better suited for www.electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: ATmega328 has only one ADC module, but it can be multiplexed to one of 8 analog inputs. You cannot force AVR to switch inputs automatically, as it done in STM channel groups, therefore, if you want to measure different channels in a row, you have to switch them manually (e.g in an ISR)

Comment: In ATmega we have ADMUX for the selection of channels, where as in STM whenever I try reading the value of two channels(rank 1 and rank 2) it seems to show value of one only.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand what the ADC means in both. Every ADC in STM32 can measure from 16 pins  (+plus internal) so you have 30+ ADCs in ATMega understanding

Comment: I got you, thank you.